# Replicate MySQL table to MariaDB for System Versioning

Tags: mysql, mariadb, replication

We have some tables in an operational and busy MySQL database (AWS RDS) for which we require system versioning for some of the tables. (point-in-time queries)

Is it possible to somehow replicate the data in to AWS RDS for MariaDB in order to leverage its [temporal table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/) capabilities?
(Adding note: replication between MySQL and MariaDB is indeed supported, as explained [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/setting-up-replication/#replicating-from-mysql-master-to-mariadb-slave))

This may also be problematic as the temporal table should be created via the "WITH SYSTEM VERSIONING" option, which adds extra columns to the table.. (so table schema will not be identical)
Any assistance or other ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: I doubt it. MySQL and MariaDB are different products. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both have been changing since then. Neither of them are making any attempt to remain compatible. Even if MySQL can currently replicate to MariaDB today, you should expect that replication compatibility will stop working soon.

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin!

Replication between MySQL and MariaDB is indeed supported (see here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/setting-up-replication/#replicating-from-mysql-master-to-mariadb-slave)

I will also take my chances with this being supported going forward.

Question is, if and how this can be used along with system versioned (temporal) tables, so we can track changes and see historical data in the MySQL source tables using the MariaDB replica.

Thanks again for your input on this!